# Permutations with repeating values and digits

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Using counting techniques answer the following questions.

a.  How many different 4-digits PINs can be produced using the digits 1,3,8,  and 7?

b.  How many different 4-digit PINs can be produced if the digits 7 and 8 must be beside each other?

c.  How many different 4-digit PINs can be produced if the digits 0, 8, 8, 7 are used?

If someone could help me figure this out it would help me sooo much! I have tried this problem using additive principal but nothing is working

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  For an exercise such as this, you should include your attempt and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Imperative: Do not just say "I tried something and it does not work," please *show* what you have tried so that we may help you find out *why* it is not working for you.

Comment: is (b) a follow-on from (a), or independent (that is does the restricted digit choice still apply)?

Comment: I dont think its a follow up

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the digits cannot be repeated because if it can be repeated, then there are quite a number of complications for 1(b).

1(a) Number of PINs that can be produced using $1,3,7,8 = 4! = 24$. There are two types of principle, addition and multiplicative. This question requires you to use multiplicative.

The explanation is as follow. The first digit can be any 4 digits, then second digit is left with any 3 remaining digits (Example you pick 1 as the first digit, you can only pick $3,7,8$ as the second digit, third digit is the remaining 2 non chosen digits, and the fourth digit is the last digit that you have no chosen). Hence there are $4.3.2.1 = 4! = 24$ ways to do so.

Assume that the digits can be repeated; Then

Number of PINs that can be produced using 1,3,8,7 (I assume the digits can repeat) = $ 4.4.4.4 = 4^4 = 256$.

The explanation is as follows: The first number of your PIN can be any 4 digits, the second digit can also be any 4 digits, the third can be any 4 digits, and the last can be any 4 digits. Hence, by the multiplicative principle, answer is $4^4 = 256$

1(b) I group $"7,8"$ together. Therefore, I just need to find the number of ways to arrange these $"3"$ digits (Why 3? Because the only digit I am concerned with is $x, y, 78$), where $x$, $y$ is an integer n between 0 to 9 inclusive but not $7$ or $8$ The number of ways to arrange these.

Then number of ways to arrange a PIN number = $(8.7.1).2!.3! = 672$. Why $8.7.1$? Because I have this set of numbers ${0,1,2,3,4,5,6,9}$. I must choose $78$ to be in my PIN number. Hence, the first digit can be any 8 elements in the set, and the second digit is any remaining 7 and the last digit is $78$. But why $2!$? This is because I can permute my $7$ and $8$. (I can have a PIN that is $1378$, and I can also have a PIN that is $1387$ since it answers the question that 7 and 8 is beside each other). But at the same time, I can also permute my 3 chosen digits. Example, I picked $2$ as my first digit, $5$ as my second digit and sadly, the third digit is forcefully chosen to be $78$. I can end up with $2578$. However, it can also be $2785$ or $7825$ or $7852$ etc.

If the digits can be repeated, then there is a problem. Why? Because what if my PIN number is 1111? Does it answers the question? Yes. Think back to the logical proposition... "If $p$, then $q$".. "If $7$ and $8$ are beside each other, then I am correct". But what if I do not have any $7$ or $8$? I am still correct (vacuously true because the hypothesis is false) So I hope I answered your question why the digits cannot repeat for (b)

1(c) The way this question is structured tells me that the digits provided cannot be repeated (which means I cannot use $8$ 3-times, or use $1$ more than once)

Hence, number of ways to get a PIN is = $\frac {4!}{2!} = 12$. You can check by listing. But the reason by we divide by $2!$ is because the digit $8$ is repeated twice.

Think of it this way: You have a this set of numbers, $0, 8_1, 8_2, 7$

I can get a PIN in this conventional manner.
$08_18_27$ and $08_28_17$. But aren't this both PIN number the same? Because of the number of times we can permute $8_1$ and $8_2$, which is $2!$ number of times, we need to reverse this permutation by dividing it away.

Hope it clarifies!